# List within a string and print formatting

Tags: python

I am creating something which takes a tuple, converts it into a string and then reorganises the string using print formatting. 'other' can sometimes have 2 names, hence why I have used `*` and the `" ".join(other)` in this function:

```
def strFormat(x):

    #Convert to string
    s=' '
    s = s.join(x)
    print(s)

    #Split string into different parts
    payR, dep, sal, *other, surn = s.split()
    payR, dep, sal, " ".join(other), surn

    #Print formatting!
    print (surn , other, payR, dep, sal)
```

The problem with this is that it prints a list of 'other' within the string like this:

```
Jones ['David', 'Peter'] 84921 Python 63120
```

But I want it more like this:

```
Jones David Peter 84921 Python 63120
```

So that it is ready for formatting into something like this:

```
Jones, David Peter      84921 Python      £63120
```

Am I going about this the right way and how do I stop the list appearing within the string?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're close. Change this line (which does nothing):

```
payR, dep, sal, " ".join(other), surn
```

to

```
other = " ".join(other)
```

Comment: Thanks! It works now, could you explain to me what other = " ".join(other) does differently? Just want to know so I can learn from it, Thanks!

Comment: @RJB You didn't assign the result of the `.join` operation back to the variable. The returned string just disappeared into nowhere.